# URL to webview through JavaFX except we get our url data from another class?

Tags: java

Say You have a class with the JavaFX start().

This class is launched by another class, with main. I want to get information from the class with main, to the class with JavaFX. For some reason, a constructor won't work.

Here's the code that does the webview:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class htmlRender extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("HTML");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        VBox root = new VBox();
        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        Hyperlink hpl = new Hyperlink("LINK");
        hpl.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                webEngine.load("LINK");
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(hpl, browser);
        scene.setRoot(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Where it says "LINK", I want to insert a string from another class.

The other class has

```
public static void main(String[]args){
htmlRender.launch(htmlRender.class, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX application launch parameters can be accessed via the [Application.getParameters()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--) method.